# Closing file opened as object {str}

Tags: python

I'm opening a file `bug_html_file` using `.read()` method. Python uses it as `{str}` object in memory, right?

```
bug_html_file = open(bgz_sfx_html_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Is it needed in any way to close that handle? Is there any file-handle created?

Comment: use `with open(bgz_sfx_html_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: contents = f.read()` so you're explicit about closing the file handle

Comment: There is no way to close that handle manually, but Python will still do it when the program ends or during garbage collection. However, that is a bad way to handle files, don't worry about using one more line to have the file object in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always close the files you open. If, for example, you run that in an interpreter and then you later, with the interpreter still open, try to delete the file, you won't be able to, because the file is flagged as "in use".
The way you open that file, you lose the file object's reference (returned by `open`), so you can't close it afterwards.

As @Chris_Rands suggests, use a `with` block to ensure the file is closed once the block is exited:

```
with open('bug_html_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
# here the file is closed (if you try `read`ing from `fp` you'll raise an error)
```